# php regexp how to capture substring to variable

Tags: php, regex

In php if I capture a string

`$string = 'gardens, countryside @teddy135'`

how do I capture `@username` from that string to a new variable in php username begins with `@` preceded by a space and terminating in a space or the end of the string?

so I would end up with

`$string = 'gardens, countryside'
$username ='@teddy135'`

Comment: [`\s@(\w+)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/tF0nE5/1)

Comment: @Tushar you should post this as answer with explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following regex

```
\s@(\w+)\b
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tF0nE5/1)

1. `\s`: Matches one space
2. `@`: Matches `@` literally
3. `(\w+)`: Matches one or more alphanumeric characters including `_` and put it in first capturing group
4. `\b`: Word boundary

**Code:**

```
$re = "/\\s@(\\w+)\\b/"; 
$str = "gardens, countryside @teddy135 @tushar and @abc"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: would that be like
preg_match_all('\s@(\w+)\b',$string,$username);

Comment: @BarryHamilton I've added code too at the bottom of answer

Comment: cheers, I will accept when the window allows, you were very quick!

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(10) " @teddy135" [1]=> string(8) "teddy135" } 

when I dump $matches it has captured it twice once with @ and once without?

Comment: @BarryHamilton The one at index `1` is the first captured group, you can use `$matches[1]` to get the username, if you want `@` symbol too, then use `$matches[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = "/\s(@\S+)/"; 
$mystr = "gardens, countryside @teddy135 @xyz-12 and @abc.abc"; 

preg_match_all($regex, $mystr, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```